# UnicodeDecodeError on interpolating str message to Unicode logging template in Python

Tags: python-2.7, logging, unicode

I'm trying to create a utf-8 log file with Python 2.7 on Win 8. I'm always getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)` when I'm trying to log Windows paths that contain non-latin characters in them. The following setup invariably throws the dreaded `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
import logging
from logging import handlers

def GetLogger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('log')
    if not len(logger.handlers):
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.propagate = False
        # create a file handler
        fileHandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('mylog.log', when = 'midnight', backupCount = 10, encoding = 'utf-8')
        fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # unicode template here
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(u'[%(levelname)-8s: %(asctime)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s()] - %(message)s'))
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    return logger

logger = GetLogger()
path = 'e:\\\xcf\xf0\xee' + 'foo.bar' # actually I'm just calling os.getcwd() + 'foo.bar' here, and that's what it returns
print type(path) # prints <type 'str'>
logger.warning('Didn\'t find path %s' % path) # <- POOF!
# logger.warning('Didn\'t find path %s' % 'abcde') <- This would work
```

I tried wrapping `path` in `unicode(path)`, but it didn't help. I'm at my wit's end. How do I log these tricky paths?

Comment: Did you try `path = u'e:\\\xcf\xf0\xee' + u'foo.bar'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `os.getcwdu()` for the Unicode version of the current path and use Unicode strings in your `logger.warning`.

When dealing with Unicode, it's best to use Unicode strings for all text, or use Python 3.x where it becomes the default type for `'xxxx'` and `b'xxxx'` is the syntax for byte strings.  You can also use [`from __future__ import unicode_literals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) in Python 2.7 to mimic the Python 3.x behavior.  See [PEP 3112](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/) for more info.